# Transfer money using yodlee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yodlee

In my current rails application I am using yodlee to authenticate from bank and get all the banking related data like transactions,account detail, balance etc.

But now I need to transfer money from one of my yodlee associated account to other yodlee associated account.Since yodlee money movement apis are only the read only apis I am not able to find out a way to do the money transfer.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee provides read only api. You need to use another provider for transfer like mangopay.